# How can SQLAlchemy be taught to recover from a disconnect?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

According to http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic, SQLAlchemy can be instrumented to reconnect if an entry in the connection pool is no longer valid. I create the following test case to test this:

```
import subprocess
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
from sqlalchemy import exc
from sqlalchemy.pool import Pool

@event.listens_for(Pool, "checkout")
def ping_connection(dbapi_connection, connection_record, connection_proxy):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    try:
        print "pinging server"
        cursor.execute("SELECT 1")
    except:
        print "raising disconnect error"
        raise exc.DisconnectionError()
    cursor.close()

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres@localhost/test')

connection = engine.connect()

subprocess.check_call(['psql', str(engine.url), '-c',
    "select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity " +
    "where pid <> pg_backend_pid() " +
    "and datname='%s';" % engine.url.database],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

result = connection.execute("select 'OK'")
for row in result:
    print "Success!", " ".join(row)
```

But instead of recovering I receive this exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) terminating connection due to administrator command
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

Since "pinging server" is printed on the terminal it seems safe to conclude that the event listener is attached. How can SQLAlchemy be taught to recover from a disconnect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the [checkout](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.PoolEvents.checkout) method is **only** called when you first get a connection from the pool (eg your `connection = engine.connect()` line)

If you subsequently lose your connection, you will have to explicitly replace it, so you could just grab a new one, and retry your sql:

```
try:
    result = connection.execute("select 'OK'")
except sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:  # may need more exceptions here
    connection = engine.connect()  # grab a new connection
    result = connection.execute("select 'OK'")  # and retry
```

This would be a pain to do around every bit of sql, so you could wrap database queries using something like:

```
def db_execute(conn, query):
    try:
        result = conn.execute(query)
    except sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:  # may need more exceptions here (or trap all)
        conn = engine.connect()  # replace your connection
        result = conn.execute(query)  # and retry
    return result
```

The following:

```
result = db_execute(connection, "select 'OK'")
```

Should now succeed.

Another option would be to also listen for the [invalidate](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.PoolEvents.invalidate) method, and take some action at that time to replace your connection.

Comment: You seem to have confirmed that the SQLAlchemy documentation is misleading. The _Pool_ in this context of no value if every query needs to be wrapped in a helper method does does exception handling and explicit recovery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pre ping - this emits a test statement to make sure that the database connection is still viable before running the actual statement.

> The approach adds a small bit of overhead to the connection checkout process, however is otherwise the most simple and reliable approach to completely eliminating database errors due to stale pooled connections.

```py
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:pw@host/db", pool_pre_ping=True)
```

[sqlalchemy disconnect handling](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic)